# iOS app with YouTube v3 API and youtube-ios-player-helper can't autoplay videos

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I am having a problem autoplaying videos with the `youtube-ios-player-helper` pod provided by Google/YouTube. Here is the relevant part of my app (iOS 10, Swift 3):

- a ChannelVideosViewController that displays video thumbnails as UIViews with an UITapGestureRecognizer that in turn segues to my PlayerViewController and passes the videoId from the API call
- a PlayerViewController as follows:

  ```
  var youtubePlayerView = YTPlayerView() // player for videos
  var youtubeVideoID = String() // videoId from API passed by ChannelVideosViewController

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  // ... skipping UI stuff

  view.addSubview(youtubePlayerView)
  youtubePlayerView.load(withVideoId: youtubeVideoID, playerVars: ["autoplay":1,"modestbranding":1,"showinfo":0,"rel":0])
  }
  ```

With the code above the helper library successfully loads the videos and plays them in fullscreen when I press the "big red button" but I want to autoplay the videos directly after I segue into the view. Is there a way to do this?

- `"autoplay":1` from the [YouTube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls) doesn't seem to cut it for iOS.
- `youtubePlayerView.playVideo()` doesn't do anything

Comment: Hi! did the autoplay works with you?

Comment: @Llg Hi! Sadly I have gotten a bit sidetracked lately due to other projects but to answer your question - not really; I am able to play videos etc. but autoplay still doesn't work. Do you have a solution for this? Or are you having the same problem as well?

Comment: @Sadly I have the same problem :(

Comment: @Llg yeah.. maybe somebody can help at some point.. but better yet - I'll try to solve it myself :) I'll be coming back to this issue in the following weeks

Comment: can you please take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550914/swift-ytplayerstate-unstarted-and-ytplayerstate-queued-not-working and help me if you have an idea about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conform to `YTPlayerViewDelegate` protocol like this:

`self.youtubePlayer.delegate = self`

Now use this delegate method to play video automatically when player is ready:

```
extension ViewController: YTPlayerViewDelegate {
    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
        self.youtubePlayer.playVideo()
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in my case.

Comment: sorry for the belated reply - I am currently not working on the app but this seems like a cool solution; marking as answered :)

Comment: No problem...thank you for accepting the answer, it will work for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [github](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/8) the autopilot doesn't work with the iOS player, as a workaround try this one:

```
(void)playerViewDidBecomeReady:(YTPlayerView *)playerView{ [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Playback started" object:self]; [self.playerView playVideo]; }
```

For more information, check these threads:

- [AutoPlay Not working properly](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/67)
- [Using YTPlayerView to play embedded YouTube video in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972123/using-ytplayerview-to-play-embedded-youtube-video-in-ios-failed-with-restriction)

Comment: Ok I gave this a try and now that I think about it - I stumbled across this a few days ago. `playerViewDidBecomeReady` is supposed to be a delegate method of YTPlayerView but Xcode can't find it. Maybe they removed it? I also can't post a Notification with the new API without having an NSNotification.Name and "Playback started" is not available - probably due to the missing delegate method of YTPlayerView.

Comment: I'm not sure if they remove it or not. But, you can double check on that by searching it or find an issue about that.